Android Grant permissions on folder without DocumentUI
I am facing an issue with some Android devices while trying to grant permissions on user selected folders.
The application already ask for permissions and everything is fine but when the user click to choose a destination folder in devices where the DocumentUI is not present it is not possible to grant permissions. How can I allow users to select a folder and grant permissions if the device does not provide its own content provider like DocumentsUI?
Using the permissions MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not an option because the app is not a file manager app.
Thanks
